# Parsing JSON in Zig fails

Tags: json, http, zig

I am trying to fetch and parse the json from this page https://ziglang.org/download/index.json.
I use Windows 11.
I get the following error when I execute my code:

```
error: MissingField
    C:\Program Files\zig-windows-x86_64-0.12.0-dev.1637+673a1efa2\lib\std\json\static.zig:785:17: 0x7ff6dd5dc141 in fillDefaultStructValues__anon_12928 (zig.exe.obj)
                    return error.MissingField;
                    ^
    C:\Program Files\zig-windows-x86_64-0.12.0- 
   dev.1637+673a1efa2\lib\std\json\static.zig:375:13: 0x7ff6dd4fb8d8 in innerParse__anon_10633 
   (zig.exe.obj)
                try fillDefaultStructValues(T, &r, &fields_seen);
                ^
    C:\Program Files\zig-windows-x86_64-0.12.0- 
   dev.1637+673a1efa2\lib\std\json\static.zig:140:19: 0x7ff6dd4acef4 in parseFromTokenSourceLeaky__anon_7857 (zig.exe.obj)
        const value = try innerParse(T, allocator, scanner_or_reader, resolved_options);
                      ^
    C:\Program Files\zig-windows-x86_64-0.12.0- 
    dev.1637+673a1efa2\lib\std\json\static.zig:88:5: 0x7ff6dd49a48b in 
    parseFromSliceLeaky__anon_7322 (zig.exe.obj)
        return parseFromTokenSourceLeaky(T, allocator, &scanner, options);
        ^
    C:\Users\asd\Desktop\zig\src\main.zig:33:24: 0x7ff6dd49a022 in main (zig.exe.obj)
            const parsed = try std.json.parseFromSliceLeaky(
                           ^
    run zig: error: the following command exited with error code 1:
    C:\Users\asd\Desktop\zig\zig-out\bin\zig.exe
    Build Summary: 3/5 steps succeeded; 1 failed (disable with --summary none)
    run transitive failure
    └─ run zig failure
    error: the following build command failed with exit code 1:
    C:\Users\asd\Desktop\zig\zig-cache\o\decc8983be50701f9459d8ab9008fb1a\build.exe 
    C:\Program Files\zig-windows-x86_64-0.12.0-dev.1637+673a1efa2\zig.exe 
    C:\Users\asd\Desktop\zig C:\Users\kstoy\OneDrive\Desktop\zig\zig-cache 
    C:\Users\asd\AppData\Local\zig --seed 0x1f71bf2c run
```

From the error I can only assume that there are some discrepancies between my structs and the json which I am trying to parse in them, but I have compared the structs fields with the fields of the json and seems like that that's not the case. I have also played with setting the `ignore_unknown_fields` field to true, but without any difference

Here is my code:

```
const std = @import("std");
const print = std.debug.print;
const Uri = std.Uri;
const Client = std.http.Client;
const Headers = std.http.Headers;
const FetchOptions = std.http.Client.FetchOptions;
const Location = std.http.Client.FetchOptions.Location;
const ArenaAllocator = std.heap.ArenaAllocator;

pub fn main() !void {
    var page_allocator = ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer page_allocator.deinit();
    const allocator = page_allocator.allocator();

    const uri = try Uri.parse("https://ziglang.org/download/index.json");

    var client = Client{ .allocator = allocator };
    var headers = Headers{ .allocator = allocator };
    defer headers.deinit();

    try headers.append("accept", "*/*");

    var options = FetchOptions{
        .method = .GET,
        .headers = headers,
        .location = Location{ .uri = uri },
    };
    var res = try client.fetch(allocator, options);
    defer res.deinit();

    if (res.body) |body| {
        print("body: {s}", .{body});
        const parsed = try std.json.parseFromSliceLeaky(
            ZigReleases,
            allocator,
            body,
            .{ .ignore_unknown_fields = true },
        );

        const zig_releases = parsed.master;
        print("asd {}", .{zig_releases});
    } else {
        print("Request failed\n", .{});
    }
}

const ZigReleases = struct {
    master: Master,
    @"0_1_1": @"0_1_1",
    @"0_2_0": @"0_2_0",
    @"0_3_0": @"0_3_0",
    @"0_4_0": @"0_4_0",
    @"0_5_0": @"0_5_0",
    @"0_6_0": @"0_6_0",
    @"0_7_0": @"0_7_0",
    @"0_7_1": @"0_7_1",
    @"0_8_0": @"0_8_0",
    @"0_8_1": @"0_8_1",
    @"0_9_0": @"0_9_0",
    @"0_9_1": @"0_9_1",
    @"0_10_0": @"0_10_0",
    @"0_10_1": @"0_10_1",
    @"0_11_0": @"0_11_0",
};

const Master = struct {
    version: []const u8,
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"powerpc64le-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"powerpc-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_1_1" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_2_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_3_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_4_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_5_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_6_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv6kz-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_7_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv6kz-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_7_1" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_8_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_8_1" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_9_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_9_1" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_10_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_10_1" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"i386-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const @"0_11_0" = struct {
    date: []const u8,
    docs: []const u8,
    stdDocs: []const u8,
    notes: []const u8,
    src: BuildInfo,
    bootstrap: BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-freebsd": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-macos": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"armv7a-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"riscv64-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"powerpc64le-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"powerpc-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86-linux": BuildInfo,
    @"x86_64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"aarch64-windows": BuildInfo,
    @"x86-windows": BuildInfo,
};

const BuildInfo = struct {
    tarball: []const u8,
    shasum: []const u8,
    size: []const u8,
};
```

Zig version: 0.12.0-dev.1637+673a1efa2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to define this JSON file as a struct might not be the best idea. What do you plan to do when the file changes? You'd better use dynamic parsing (see [`std/json/dynamic_test.zig`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/json/dynamic_test.zig)).

Anyway, your mistakes are:

- Releases do not use `_`, but `.`, so it should be `@"0.1.1": @"0_1_1"` instead of `@"0_1_1": @"0_1_1"`.
- Version 0.7.0 does not have `armv6kz-linux`.
- Version 0.10.0 does not have `i386-windows`.

Comment: Looking at it now is so obvious. Thank you for the heads up on the dynamic parsing.